# Android -- Adding and removing items from a multiline ListView with a custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I am trying to construct a multiline ListView backed by an ArrayAdapter. I would like each row in the list to have two lines and a delete button next to it. When the delete button is clicked, the items in the arrays should be removed and the ListView should refresh itself.

This is the code for the MainActivity, which has an inner class that is the custom ArrayAdapter:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ArrayList<String> artistsList = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] artists = {"Matt Nathanson", "Green Day", "Three Days Grace", "LMFAO", "One Direction", 
        "Linkin Park", "Neon Trees", "Cee Lo Green", "Plain White T's", "Metallica", "Maroon 5",
        "Sick Puppies", "Bruno Mars", "Billy Joel", "Don McLean", "Adele", "Gary Jules"};
ArrayList<String> songsList = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] songs = {"Come On Get Higher", "Holiday", "I Hate Everything About You", "Sexy and I Know It", "What Makes You Beautiful",
        "What I've Done", "Animal", "Fuck You", "Hey There Delilah", "Sandman", "Moves Like Jagger",
        "Rip Tide", "Talking to the Moon", "Piano Man", "American Pie", "Someone Like You", "Mad World"};

ListView list;
TestArrayAdapter mArrayAdapter;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    for(String s : artists) {
        artistsList.add(s);
    }
    for(String s : songs) {
        songsList.add(s);
    }

    mArrayAdapter = new TestArrayAdapter();

    list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mainlist);

    list.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);
}


class TestArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public TestArrayAdapter() {
        super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.row, songs);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

        TextView primaryTextView = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.primaryTextView);
        TextView secondaryTextView = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.secondaryTextView);

        primaryTextView.setText(songsList.get(position));
        secondaryTextView.setText(artistsList.get(position));

        ImageView deleteButton = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.deleteRowButton);
        deleteButton.setTag(position);
        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                artistsList.remove(v.getTag());
                songsList.remove(v.getTag());
                mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return row;
    }
}
```

Calling notifyDataSetChanged() does not seem to do anything; however, the items in the ArrayLists are being deleted. The ListView seems to be independent of changes that I make in the ArrayLists and the ArrayAdapter. Ideally, when I remove an item from the underlying data, I should be able to call notifyDataSetChanged() and the ListView will update itself.

I have looked at the other questions similar to this, but all of them have only a single ArrayList providing data to the ListView, and I can't figure out how to adapt those solutions for multiline rows. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a tutorial recently on how to create a similar listview. Check it out here

http://www.shubhayu.com/android/listview-with-arrayadapter-and-customized-items

This would help you in creating what you want except the deletion part. The deletion will not be difficult after that. You just need to handle it on the onClick of your delete button. I'll guide you through it once you get the list up and running.

Also, override you getCount(). That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks very much! This tutorial was very helpful. I got it to delete the items.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, I suggest you use it.  You are using two strings for maintaining the data, create a class and use that class to create arrayadapter. I'm posting an example from my current (incomplete) codes.

I use my custom ArrayAdapter as a singleton and keep modifying it through the instance. I also have a service running that maintains a backup of the data in the event Android destroys the singleton from memory. Everytime i do a notifydatasetchanged, I backup the rules in a public static variable inside that service. You can ignore this part because its only required for my case.

```
public class RuleManager extends ArrayAdapter<Rule>
{
  private static RuleManager mInstance;
  private final Context context;

  private RuleManager(Context context, List<Rule> r)
  {
    super(context,R.layout.main_menu_options_list_item);
    if(r==null)r=new ArrayList<Rule>();
    this.context=context;
  }
  public static synchronized RuleManager getInstance(Context context,List<Rule> r) 
  {
      if (mInstance == null)
      {   
          if(r==null)
              r=CallMonitor.ruleBackup;  //A service that contains copy of entire data (as a backup if android destroys stuffs)
          mInstance = new RuleManager(context, r);
      }
      return mInstance;
  }     

  public void addRule(Rule rule) 
  {
      add(rule);
      notifyDataSetChanged();
      backupRules();
  } 
  private void backupRules()
  {
      CallMonitor.ruleBackup=null;
      CallMonitor.ruleBackup=new ArrayList<Rule>();
      for(int i=0;i<getCount();i++)
          CallMonitor.ruleBackup.add(getItem(i));
  }
  public void editRule(int position,Rule rule)
  {

      getItem(position).setAbc(rule.getAbc);
      getItem(position).setDef(rule.getDef());
      getItem(position).setGhi(rule.getGhi());
      getItem(position).setJkl(rule.getJkl());
      notifyDataSetChanged();
      backupRules();

  }
  public boolean deleteRule(int position)
  {
       try
       {
           remove(getItem(position));
           notifyDataSetChanged();
           backupRules();
           return true;
       }
       catch(Exception e)
       {
           return false;
       }       
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.row, songs);
```

Why do you have this in the adapter constructor passing list of `songs`.

I'm  not sure, as i haven't implemented listview with multiple data resources(2 lists in ur case).

But the ideal way of doing it would be to create a new class ( in your case it would just have two strings : Songs , artists). such that **Single** object of that class represents a single row information in list view. And thus passing that to your custom adapter, and in getView() using data from that class objects for list view.

In your case , notifydatasetchanged() might not be working because you have set `songs` to be the `objects to represent in the ListView`in the constructor of adapter and that is not changing ever... thus list is not refreshing at all...